# success with ASUS MB169B+ thunderbolt 2MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

Has anyone successfully used the ASUS MB169B+ with thunderbolt 2 Mac Book Pro? i personally have a late 2015 MBP and i see mixed reviews and explanations all over the place. i tried this before with no success. i know there are new solutions (display link drivers https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/macos) as of recently and im curious if the situation has changed.

What connector and cable and adapters have people gotten good results between this  monitor and Thunderbolt 2 MacBook Pro?

Comment: how did you make it work?